# How to upload .txt file through PHP script to Github using API?

Tags: php, api, github, curl

So I’ve been working on this script for the past 3 days for my company to get a log file automatically sent to my Github repository. I expected this to be quite easy actually (boy was I mistaken) and have no idea how to use the API to send over information. After doing quite a bit of research, I found another user’s post here:
https://github.community/t/how-to-upload-a-file-using-github-api/14031

The main code that appears to be beneficial is this chunk:

```
<?php
$file_git = "wall.jpg";
$data_git = array(
'sha'=>file_get_contents("sha.txt"),
'message'=>'image',
'content'=> base64_encode($file_git),
'committer'=> array(
'name'=>'Jacob',
'email' => '45331093+greenandgreen@users.noreply.github.com'
)
);
$data_string_git = json_encode($data_git);
$ch_git = curl_init('https://api.github.com/repos/YOUR_REPO/contents/wall.jpg');
curl_setopt($ch_git, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "PUT");
curl_setopt($ch_git, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string_git);
curl_setopt($ch_git, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch_git, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
'Content-Type: application/json',
'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/76.0.3809.132 YaBrowser/19.9.3.314 Yowser/2.5 Safari/537.36',
'Authorization: token PLACE_YOUR_PERSONAL_TOKEN_HERE'
));
$result_git = curl_exec($ch_git);
echo $result_git;
$p_git = json_decode($result_git);
file_put_contents("sha.txt",$p_git->content->sha);
?>
```

The problem that I'm having trying to use this is that the curl_init function can't seem to reach my repository (I also may be setting it up wrong).  What I have is this:

```
$file_git = $filename;
$data_git = array(
    'sha'=>file_get_contents($shafile),
    'message'=>'text',
    'content'=> base64_encode($file_git),
    'committer'=> array(
    'name'=>'JOSH',
    'email' => 'USER@EMAIL.COM')
);

$data_string_git = json_encode($data_git);
$ch_git = curl_init('https://api.github.com/repos/updateCollection/contents/' . $filename);
curl_setopt($ch_git, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "PUT");
curl_setopt($ch_git, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string_git);
curl_setopt($ch_git, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch_git, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'Content-Type: application/json',
    'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/76.0.3809.132 YaBrowser/19.9.3.314 Yowser/2.5 Safari/537.36',
    'Authorization: token PERSONALACCESSTOKEN_TOKEN_LISTED_HERE'
));

$result_git = curl_exec($ch_git);
echo $result_git;
$p_git = json_decode($result_git);
file_put_contents("sha.txt",$p_git->content->sha);
```

The error message that I'm getting is " "message": "Not Found", "documentation_url": "https://developer.github.com/v3" "
The overall goal is to place this .txt file into my respository under updateCollection/tree/simplehistorylogs but I can't seem to get there.

**TLDR:** I am trying to upload a .txt file through Github API using PHP script and cannot get file into repository, or reach the repository.

Comment: So I found a few corrections that get me closer to the end result.

The code listing above works only for public repositories.
The curl_init requires the owner name before the repos (joshg/repos/updateCollection/contents/{file path}
The name is the only piece actually sending over with this script; the contents of the file do not get moved most likely as a result of this piece here that is displayed from the echo:

Comment: For those that are looking for this solution, I was unable to find exactly what I was looking for but found a similar solution that avoids the API call limit and is still sufficient for my purposes.  Instead of storing every record in a text file, I sent each record directly over to GitHub as a filename; there's no limit to the amount of calls but you must use the Sleep() function in order to avoid abuse rates.  Hope this helps some wary searcher.